# Convert TIFF to GeoTIFF

Tags: convert, geotiff-tiff

I have a TIFF created from a pdf using GIMP2. The co-ordinate pairs for the extents are shown in the TIFF. I need to convert this TIFF to a GeoTiff and ultimately to a shpfile. The CRS is known.

[image]

Comment: i think this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956818/create-geotiff-from-tiff-and-4-corners-latitude-and-longitude

Comment: Perhaps the georeferencer in QGIS is easier for a beginner.

Comment: Can you say what the CRS is? This should be reasonably easy to do with GDAL if you can create a world-file.

Comment: @BradHards, I have the CRS info.

Comment: UTM21s on SAD69

Comment: @user3338197, thanks, I have installed gdal and attempted to create a geotiff but this new geotiff does not align with my reference data set which is in the same co-ordinate system.